# scp to a symlink to a mounted hard drive failed

Tags: linux, external-hard-drive, mount, symbolic-link, scp

I tried to scp from an external machine to my machine but failed:

```
$ scp -rp /home/externaluser/pd/folder myIP:pd/
scp: pd/: File exists
```

I have checked the permission:

```
$ ls -l /home/externaluser/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 externaluser externaluser   56 Mar  3 17:42 pd -> /run/media/superuser/external_xfs_hd/pd
```

And the folder is empty:

```
$ ll /run/media/superuser/external_xfs_hd/pd
total 0
```

The strange thing is that if I scp to /home/externaluser then it works:

```
$ scp -rp /home/externaluser/pd/folder myIP:
```

Any idea?

Update #1:
Followed Danfossi's suggestion to try rsync:

```
$ rsync -avz -e ssh /home/externaluser/pd externaluser@myIP:/home/externaluser/pd
sending incremental file list
rsync: ERROR: cannot stat destination "/home/externaluser/pd": Permission denied (13)
rsync error: errors selecting input/output files, dirs (code 3) at main.c(565) [Receiver=3.0.9]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (187 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.1]
$
```

Here is the info of the mounted external drive:

```
$ df -T /dev/sdb
Filesystem     Type  1K-blocks  Used  Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb       xfs  1952560720 32992 1952527728   1% /run/media/superuser/external_xfs_hd
```

It was mounted by nautilus when I clicked on it.

Answer (score 1):

Try with rsync:

```
$ rsync -avz -e ssh /src/dir user@remote.host:dst/dir
```

or with tar:

```
$ cd /source_dir
$ tar cf - * | ssh user@remote.host ‘(cd /destination_dir;tar xf - )’
```

Comment: More info but still doesn't work :(

Comment: how do you mount the external drive ? I do not remember in what situation but I had a similar writing problem on the mount points under /run.
Try to mount the external disk manually on a folder under /mnt

Comment: It was mounted by nautilus when I (as superuser) clicked on it.

Comment: just to be sure I would tell you to try to temporarily change the mount point and try again

Comment: Good that you asked how I mounted.  And I checked the permissions of all the parent directories of the mounted drive.  Now, I noticed that `nautilus` used `superuser` as the owner of `/run/media/superuser` and set the directory to non executable for everyone except owner and group, causing `externaluser` not able to stat, which `rsync` was trying to do.  Fixing the permission fixes everything.  Thanks a lot for your hint!